# Unable to use encrypt option on s3cmd

Tags: ubuntu, encryption, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I have two simple scripts to upload and download some code to and from S3 on Amazon web services:

```
#####Upload Script
zip -r file.zip www
s3cmd del s3://mybucket/file.zip --encrypt
s3cmd put file.zip s3://mybucket --encrypt
rm -rf file.zip

#####Download Script
rm -rf /home/ubuntu/www/*
s3cmd sync s3://mybucket/file.zip /home/ubuntu/ --encrypt
unzip -u /home/ubuntu/file.zip -d /home/ubuntu/
rm -rf /home/ubuntu/file.zip
```

However these scripts only work when I don't use the `--encrypt` option. The resulting file has 11MB without encrypt and it unzips just fine, and 9MB using encrypt but gives me an error when I try to unzip it. How do I decrypt files from S3 since there is no `--decrypt` option and using `--encrypt` on the download also didn't worked?

I configured s3cmd correctly with encryption password, and it passed the config test. Here goes the error before anybody asks:

```
Archive:  /home/ubuntu/file2.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
note:  /home/ubuntu/file2.zip may be a plain executable, not an archive
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /home/ubuntu/file2.zip or
        /home/ubuntu/file2.zip.zip, and cannot find /home/ubuntu/file2.zip.ZIP, period.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encryption appears to be broken in current upstream master branch HEAD 81e3842f7afb.  You are best off encrypting, and the putting the encrypted file, directly.  Certainly --encrypt with the [sync] command does not work.

Comment: Thanks! Encryption also seems to be broken on zip/unzip packages. Had to use gpg to solve my problem. That is happening on the latest Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when I tried downloading the backups directly from S3 rather than using `s3cmd get` to retrieve the file. When I used s3cmd to retrieve it, the file unzipped without any problem. You do not need to run it with any flags for it to decrypt. It will do it intuitively.